# VHDL code error

Tags: vhdl

I have this code for a Serial Adder in VHDL. I am trying to get it to work, but I keep on getting an error that says:

Errors found in VHDL File -

Line : 17, Error : Index constraint expected in the subtype indication

This error is referring to the line:

```
signal state, next_state : integer range 0 to 3;
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help? Please find the full code below.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity adder is
 port(
 start : in std_logic;
 clk : in std_logic;
 a_out : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
 );
end adder;

architecture behave of adder is
signal a, b : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal shift : std_logic;
signal Cin, Cout : std_logic;
signal sum_in : std_logic;
signal state, next_state : integer range 0 to 3;

begin
 sum_in <= a(0) xor b(0) xor Cin;
 Cout <= (Cin and a(0))or(Cin and b(0))or(a(0) and b(0));
 a_out <= a;

 process(state, start)
 begin
  case state is
   when 0 =>
   if start = '1' then shift <= '1'; next_state <= 1;
   else shift <= '0'; next_state <= 2; end if;
    when 1 => shift <= '1'; next_state <= 2;
    when 2 => shift <= '1'; next_state <= 3;
    when 3 => shift <= '1'; next_state <= 0;
   end case;

 end process;

 process(clk)
 begin
  if clk'event and clk = '0' then
   state <= next_state;
   if shift = '1' then
    a <= sum_in & a(3 downto 1);
    b <= b(0) & b(3 downto 1);
    Cin <= Cout;
   end if;
  end if;

 end process;

end behave;
```

Comment: Which tool are you using? Your code analyses well with ModelSim, and also anlayses and synthesizes well with Quartus 13.1.

Comment: In what context (what tool0?  Your code is valid VHDL and analyzes. You appear to be encountering a tool limitation. Note that without initializing a and b this won't do anything interesting during simulation.

Comment: I'm using Edwinxp. It has a function that allows VHDL to Schematic conversion. I'm trying to utilize it, but to no avail..

Comment: Sounds like a tool bug; maybe try to rewrite the code declaring a subtype for `integer range 0 to 3`.

Comment: @MortenZilmer could you provide an example that would work?

Comment: Appears to be a tool limitation, it's not accepting constrained integer scalars. What happens if you remove the constraint from the integer and put an others choice in your case statement?  You could also try an enumerated type for state and next state.

Comment: For a start you could try to replace with `subtype integer_0_to_3 is integer range 0 to 3; signal state, next_state : integer_0_to_3;`, but if it works around the bug is hard to say until you try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your line in which you are getting error by:
`signal state, next_state : integer is range 0 to 3;`

If you are specifying range then you should use `is range` instead of `range`